# wpdb->term_taxonomy count posts from both published and private posts?

Tags: query, wpdb, terms

I'm trying to understand why this query won't include both private and published posts when counting and sorting the taxonomy terms.

```
            $taxonomyTypes         = "AND ( tax.taxonomy = '" . implode( "' OR tax.taxonomy = '", $this->options['autocomplete_taxonomies'] ) . "') ";
        $queryStringTaxonomies = 'SELECT term.term_id as id, term.name as post_title, term.slug as guid, tax.taxonomy, 0 AS content_frequency, 0 AS title_frequency FROM ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' tax ' .
                                 'LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->terms . ' term ON term.term_id = tax.term_id WHERE 1 = 1 ' .
                                 'AND term.name LIKE "%' . $term . '%" ' .
                                 $taxonomyTypes .
                                 'ORDER BY tax.count DESC ' .
                                 'LIMIT 0, ' . $this->options['autocomplete_numrows'];
        $tempTerms             = $wpdb->get_results( $queryStringTaxonomies );
        foreach ( $tempTerms as $term ) {
            $tempObject = array(
                'id'       => $term->id,
                'type'     => 'taxonomy',
             'hide_empty' => false,
                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                'postType' => null
            );
```

The code above is not written by me but i am trying to modify it so that it also include private posts. I was hoping that

```
'hide_empty' => false,
```

Would make the query include private posts when sorting the taxonomy terms but it appears it does not, what have i missed here, how can i get the query to include both private and published posts when sorting the taxonomy terms?